# How to subclass a UIAlert?

Tags: ios

The code we're working with specified this in .h:

```
//
//  UIAlertView+error.h
//  iApplication
//
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface UIAlertView(error)

+(void)error:(NSString*)msg;

@end
```

I have a dilemma when choosing a class for a UIAlert: does it inherit from UIViewController or something else?

Comment: This question does not make sense to me. UIAlertView is an existing UIKit class and we can't choose what it inherits from. Also, it is deprecated in iOS8! (It inherits from UIView, see https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/index.html).

Comment: it seems these days, that if something is deprecated by Apple, it still works to some extent. my app uses push segues that were titled (deprocated) but they still work...Ill see if i can get it running.

Comment: BTW - that isn't subclassing. That is a class extension.

Answer (score 0):

The above code looks like an objective-C category on `UIAlertView`. It does not inherit from `UIAlertView`, instead it adds the `+(void)error:(NSString*)msg;` method to the **class** at runtime.

I wouldn't recommend doing any of that, if you'd like to like to add an `error` accessor to an **instance** of an alert, I'd look into subclassing the newer `UIAlertController`

Comment: could I switch the UIAlert with UIAlertController system?